# Getting service properties using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, map-service, arcgis-platform, getcapabilities

I am trying to find a way to get certain service properties from multiple published map services. One thing I am looking for is all services with "Feature Access" capabilities enabled:

[image: Service Properties]

I've managed to get the errors and warnings with a Python script by creating SDDrafts as it is described [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm).

In code example 7 I found this passage:

```
# Turn on feature access capabilities
configProps = doc.getElementsByTagName('Info')[0]
propArray = configProps.firstChild
propSets = propArray.childNodes
for propSet in propSets:
    keyValues = propSet.childNodes
    for keyValue in keyValues:
        if keyValue.tagName == 'Key':
            if keyValue.firstChild.data == "WebCapabilities":
                keyValue.nextSibling.firstChild.data = "Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing"
```

I searched the SDDraft files for "Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing". But this is not only included in files with Feature Access enabled but also in all other files I've checked.

Would GetCapabilities be an option to get the right information?